Do Area51 recommendations apply to public beta only, or are they good for a private beta, too?
On the Area 51 page for Crypto, there are a few recommended levels of questions, answers, visits, users, &c. Are these recommendations applicable to a private beta, or just public betas?
For example, (and this is the one that most worries me), the visits/day for this site is 47, while Area 51 recommends at least 500. Is there anything we can do about it right now, or is it only after we go into public beta that those stats should be improved?

I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not specific to cryptography. It should either be migrated to Area51, the new generic meta site or deleted. It's probably out of date as well, so we could keep it for sentimental reasons, I'll protect it.

@Maarten: Just curious, but is there an actual reason for closing/protecting this old, answered and accepted meta question? (And does bumping the rep needed to add more answers from 5 to 10 really make any difference?) Not that it really matters either way, but I'm just wondering about the sudden interest in this old question, given that I don't see any recent deleted answers or other obvious explanation.

@IlmariKaronen There is a lot happening in my life right now, so I'll be buggered if I remember, Ilmari. I think there was some activity, but I'm not sure. I was mainly here to see where we stand right now and to think out some good theme for when we go out of beta.

The Area 51 statistics give you running progress report on the site. Cryptography SE isn't even a public site, yet,  and has plenty of time to build up an audience before graduation. You can read more about that process and what those numbers mean at
Does this site have a chance of succeeding?

These numbers are guidelines for successfully exiting the public beta. It is not really realistic to have much more than 500 visits per day with only 225 people which are able to visit at all (of which 188 signed up).
For us entering the public beta, the most important thing seems to be a good number of questions (and answers), so new people don't find an empty site here, but instead can see what kind of questions are appropriate here.
Of course, given that there is now a low level of new questions, low visit count directly follows (= there is nothing new).
